# connecting linux device to a tablet via usb

Tags: usb, ethernet, android

I can connect my Linux device (an embedded device) to a tablet in the following way:

1. Use a micro USB to Ethernet cable converter
2. use a USB to Ethernet on my Linux device.
3. connect the two device to each other via Ethernet

But it is a bit ugly. Is there any way that I connect the two device via USB and then use IP communication to communicate between the two device?

The table runs Android and the device runs Ubuntu.

The reason that I want to do this is follow:

I have a web server on my embedded system and I want to allow users to connect to it using a USB cable and use a browser to change parameters on embedded device.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see what the kernel configs looks like:

```
cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep  CONFIG_USB_ETH
```

Output:

```
bob@bob-NE722:~/Downloads/odoo-8.0$ cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep CONFIG_USB_ETH
CONFIG_USB_ETH=m
CONFIG_USB_ETH_RNDIS=y
CONFIG_USB_ETH_EEM=y
```

This indicates that compiled into the ubuntu kernel is support for RNDIS and EEM, but usb ethernet emulation has to be loaded as a module.

Lets see if `g_ether` is included:

```
bob@bob-NE722:~/Downloads/odoo-8.0$ locate g_ether
/lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/g_ether.ko
/lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/g_ether.ko
```

And then:

```
sudo modprobe g_ether
```

And configure the usb ip address:

```
ifconfig usb# 192.168.0.#
```

And enable on boot:

```
echo g_ether > /etc/modules-load.d/g_ether.conf
```

And on the android device:

There should be a setting to enable usb tethering.

```
Settings --> Wireless & Networks --> Internet tethering
```

or `Tethering & Hotspots`

See:
 - http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/android_tethering#USB_tethering

Comment: And on the tablet-side enable reverse tethering or something similar?

Comment: @Nils I haven't used a lot of android devices, but I thought there was a setting to enable usb tethering? `Settings --> Wireless & Networks --> Internet tethering` or `Tethering & Hotspots` See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/android_tethering#USB_tethering

Comment: You should add that note to your answer. I am not sure wether tethering will do work as expected in this constellaton,  but it might work.